# RoboVM and libgdx iOS sample apps fail with 'Struct class must be final'

Tags: libgdx, robovm

I am trying to port a libgdx android app to iOS and am testing the sample libgdx apps to get a feel for how to connect the dots.  I was able to get the IOSDemo app to successfully run on the simulator, but all of the sample libgdx apps fail with the error:

```
    An internal error occured during: "Launching cuboc-iosrobovm".
        Struct class must be final
```

The console output is:

```
    12/29/13 1:04:04 AM: [ INFO] Building executable    
    12/29/13 1:04:08 AM: [DEBUG] Compiling org.robovm.rt.bro.ptr.BytePtr$Ptr (ios x86)
```

Followed by the error dialog.  I attempted to follow the directions for setting up the environment, but I am puzzled why the IOSDemo successfully compiles the class and all of the libgdx apps cannot.  Here is the additional information from the error log.

Exception Stack Trace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Struct class must be final
      at org.robovm.compiler.ClassCompiler.compile(ClassCompiler.java:514)
      at org.robovm.compiler.ClassCompiler.compile(ClassCompiler.java:279)
      at org.robovm.compiler.AppCompiler.compile(AppCompiler.java:198)
      at org.robovm.compiler.AppCompiler.compile(AppCompiler.java:216)
      at org.robovm.eclipse.internal.AppCompilerThread.run(AppCompilerThread.java:60)
```

Session Data:

```
    eclipse.buildId=4.3.0.M20130911-1000
    java.version=1.7.0_45
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86_64, WS=cocoa, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product 
      -keyring /Users/dev/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
    Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86_64 
      -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
      -data /Users/dev/Files/workspace/libgdx 
      -keyring /Users/dev/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

My setup: Mac OS X Mavericks, Eclipse 4.3, Xcode 5.0.1, RoboVM 0.0.7, libgdx @ origin/HEAD.

I have tried several branches of libgdx and several of the RoboVM nightlies from 0.0.8 and tried back to 0.0.6.  I assume its a configuration setting, but I am stuck.  I appreciate any help finding a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Java to native framework built into RoboVM, Bro, is currently undergoing some major refactorings. The problem you're experiencing is probably due to using a RoboVM nightly version of the libraries and an incompatible version of the RoboVM Eclipse plugin. Make sure you use the same version of the RoboVM libraries as the version of the Eclipse plugin, e.g. 0.0.7.

If you want to use the latest nightly libraries (not recommended) you should also use a nightly build of the Eclipse plugin. Use the update site http://download.robovm.org/nightlies/eclipse/ in Eclipse to get the latest nightly version.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I experienced the initial problem using the default RoboVM plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace.  I only tried the nightlies to see if it was possible an earlier or a later version might resolve the issue.  Just in case, I removed the plugin and reinstalled the plugin (0.0.7) off the marketplace and unfortunately I am still experiencing the problem.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Upon further review, your comment lead me to examine the project gdx-backend-robovm.  It had references to local robovm jar files.  I replaced those references with the latest jar files from the plugin folder and I had success launching super jumper on the simulator.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.